# Shell_NotifyIcon from RGB data

Tags: python, pywin32, system-tray, trayicon, loadimage

I have an icon in memory (RGB or whatever format I want via PIL/Pillow) and I want to use it with

```
win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon
```

which requires an `HICON`.
How do I get my RGB pixels into an HICON?

Or, even though that's wasteful, I wouldn't even mind doing a round trip via a temporary file and reloading it using `win32gui.LoadImage`, something like this:

```
from PIL import Image
#create example image with empty pixels:
img = Image.frombuffer("RGB", (32, 32), "\0"*32*32*3, "raw", "RGB", 0, 1)
img = img.convert("P")
img = img.resize((64, 64), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save("C:\\temp.ico", format="bmp")
import win32gui, win32api, win32con
flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
win32gui.LoadImage(None, "C:\\temp.ico", win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, flags)
```

But this fails with: `pywintypes.error: (0, 'LoadImage', 'No error message available')`

I just can't find a picture format that I can write to that can then be read back and used correctly by `LoadImage` in `IMAGE_ICON` mode. It seems that `LoadImage` only supports `ICO` files in that mode: I can read back `PNG` or `BMP` data as `IMAGE_BITMAP`, but the resulting handle cannot be used by `Shell_NotifyIcon`.
Is there a way to convert the `IMAGE` into an `HICON` instead? (in memory)

Comment: I think the third parameter passed to `LoadImage` should be `win32con.IMAGE_BITMAP`.

Comment: If you read the whole post, you will see that when using `IMAGE_BITMAP` "the resulting handle cannot be used by `Shell_NotifyIcon`".

Comment: Sorry about that. I read something that said "I don't know if this applies for all cases, but on WinXP an .ico can be a bmp of size 16x16, 32x32 or 64x64. Just change the extension to ico from bmp and you're ready to go."

Comment: If renaming the .bmp extension to .ico trick doesn't work, I think you're out-of-luck. Because PIL only supports reading .ico files. It's a simple format, so you might be able write your own convertor using the information in Wikipedia article titled [_ICO (file format_)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28icon_image_file_format%29).

Comment: @martineau I've updated the example code to using a 64x64 image saved with the ".ICO" extension, it still fails with '`No error message available`'.
If I have to write code myself (for such a trivial thing!?), then I'd rather write code that avoids using a temporary file and create the `HICON` directly in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how I missed that, but there is a function called [CreateIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which takes pixel data as input, and although this one is missing from pywin32's [win32gui](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui.html), there is a [CreateIconIndirect](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__CreateIconIndirect_meth.html) instead, which is just as good.

So the code becomes simply (still using a temporary file):

```
img = win32gui.LoadImage(None, "C:\\tmp.bmp", win32con.IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, flags)
pyiconinfo = (True, 0, 0, img, img)
hicon = win32gui.CreateIconIndirect(pyiconinfo)
```

To get the RGB pixels from a PIL image into a bitmap without using a temporary file, I've used this code (yes, it is very slow doing it this way, but it is relatively simple and easy to read, and I really could not care less about performance in this case):

```
def img_to_bitmap(image, pixel_value):
    hdc = win32gui.CreateCompatibleDC(0)
    dc = win32gui.GetDC(0)
    hbm = win32gui.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, size, size)
    hbm_save = win32gui.SelectObject(hdc, hbm)
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(size):
            pixel = image.getpixel((x, y))
            v = pixel_value(pixel)
            win32gui.SetPixelV(hdc, x, y, v)
    win32gui.SelectObject(hdc, hbm_save)
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, hdc)
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, dc)
    return hbm
```

For those that care about performance, a better solution probably involves [CreateDIBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [SetDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162973%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The more complete code can now be found in `set_icon_from_data` method of [this tray icon wrapper class](http://xpra.org/trac/browser/xpra/trunk/src/xpra/platform/win32/win32_NotifyIcon.py), it deals with splitting the alpha channel into its own bitmap so we can display transparent images properly too.